# CSS animations - classList only changes first instance

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm trying to apply an animation to multiple elements of the same class (.whiteKey). The following code only adds it to the first instance of the element. Why is this?

```
document.querySelector('.whiteKey').classList.add('keysAnimate');
```

& the HTML:

```
<button class="whiteKey"></button>
<button class="whiteKey"></button>
<button class="whiteKey"></button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelector()` selects only the first element with that id/class. You will need to select the buttons using `querySelectorAll()`, then iterate through them with a loop.

**HTML:**

```
<button class="whiteKey"></button>
<button class="whiteKey"></button>
<button class="whiteKey"></button>
```

**JS:**

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".whiteKey");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].classList.add('keysAnimate');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) return only the frist elment that matches in the dom. What you need is [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Then you would do something like

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".whiteKey");
elements.forEach(element => element.classList.add('keysAnimate'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @iamcastelli, but I tried that after seeing it in another thread, and it doesn't work. My updated code:


`document.querySelectorAll('.whiteKey').classList.add('keysAnimate');`

The error from console:

`(index):77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):77)`

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, not a single node.

Comment: Yeah, then they would have to iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other answers, you should use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) then you should loop through all the results nodes, you can use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through them and add the class to the class list, here is a working snippet:

```js
let whiteKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.whiteKey');

whiteKeys.forEach((el) => {
  el.classList.add('keysAnimate');
});
```

```css
.keysAnimate {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button class="whiteKey">button 1</button>
<button class="whiteKey">button 2</button>
<button class="whiteKey">button 3</button>
```